# AWS IOS IoT sample MQTT connection failed

Tags: amazon-web-services

I've been trying to run the AWS IOS IoT sample from https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples/tree/master/IoT-Sample/Swift. However, when I click the "Connect" button in the app, I get the below error. MQTT connection fails. How can I fix this?

```
2019-08-20 20:19:29:065 IoTSampleSwift[87568:16809125] Attempting to 
reconnect.
connection status = 1
Connecting...
2019-08-20 20:19:29:065 IoTSampleSwift[87568:16809125] user metadata is : ?SDK=iOS&Version=2.10.2
2019-08-20 20:19:29:065 IoTSampleSwift[87568:16809125] Metrics collection is: Enabled
2019-08-20 20:19:29:066 IoTSampleSwift[87568:16809130] <<<NSThread: 0x6000029d2500>{number = 9, name = (null)}>> Initializing MQTTEncoder and MQTTDecoder streams
2019-08-20 20:19:29:066 IoTSampleSwift[87568:16809130] opening encoder stream.
2019-08-20 20:19:29:067 IoTSampleSwift[87568:16809130] opening decoder stream.
2019-08-20 20:19:29.067789-0700 IoTSampleSwift[87568:16809130] CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9810)
2019-08-20 20:19:29.067943-0700 IoTSampleSwift[87568:16809130] TCP Conn 0x0 SSLHandshake failed (-9810)
2019-08-20 20:19:29:068 IoTSampleSwift[87568:16809130] MQTT session error, code: 3
2019-08-20 20:19:29:068 IoTSampleSwift[87568:16809130] closing encoder stream.
2019-08-20 20:19:29:068 IoTSampleSwift[87568:16809130] closing decoder stream.
2019-08-20 20:19:30:071 IoTSampleSwift[87568:16809130] MQTTSessionEventConnectionError: Received an MQTT session connection error
connection status = 5
Connection Error
```

My IoT Policy looks like this:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:*",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

And my Unauth Cognito Role looks like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "mobileanalytics:PutEvents",
                "cognito-sync:*",
                "cognito-identity:*",
                "dynamodb:*",
                "cloudwatch:*",
                "events:*",
                "iot:GetThingShadow",
                "iot:UpdateThingShadow",
                "iot:Subscribe",
                "iot:Connect",
                "iot:AttachPrincipalPolicy",
                "iot:CreateKeysAndCertificate",
                "iot:CreateCertificateFromCsr"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you share more details on the code you are using to connect and the application on IoT Core you are connecting to? Possibly is a misconfiguration in that aspect.

Answer (score 0):

If your role and policy are correct then make sure your endpoint URL in the app is in the format as below

```
https://xxxxxxx-ats.iot.REGION.amazonaws.com
```

It should have `https://` added in front of it otherwise it will keep on throwing the same error.